# Can I import Pokémon from my Let's Go team into Pokémon Home without the original game?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go, pokemon-home

I recently discovered the existence of Pokémon Home, which (among other features) allows to migrate Pokémon from Let's Go Eevee/Pikachu to Sword/Shield.

Therefore, via this app, I have been able to easily export my favorite Pokémon from the old Let's Go Eevee savegame in my Switch, **except the 6 ones in my team**.

Unfortunately, I sold my Let's Go Eevee cartridge a few months ago after clearing the game, so I cannot reload my savegame, swap my team with dull Pokémon and save to unlock them.

**Is there any way to bypass/solve this without the game**, or am I forced to get (again) a copy of Let's Go Eevee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't transfer Pokemon in your party. You need a copy of the game to move the Pokemon from your party to your Box before they can be transferred.

If you have a friend who has a copy of the game, that would save you from having to rebuy the game.

Comment: Yep, that's what I feared. I'll look for a friend... or let my Pokémon enjoy a well deserved retirement in Kanto ;). Thank you for your answer !